# Flutter firebase - update packeges

Tags: flutter

I try to update firebase to nullsafe.
Here is my pubspec:

```
   firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
  firebase_crashlytics: "^0.4.0+1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0+1"
  cloud_functions: "^0.9.0"
  firebase_storage: "^7.0.0"
  firebase_messaging: "^8.0.0-dev.15"
  firebase_remote_config: "^0.8.0-dev.0"
  firebase_analytics: "^7.0.1"
  firebase_database: "^6.0.0"
  firebase_dynamic_links: "^0.7.0+1"
  firebase_in_app_messaging: "^0.3.0+1"
  firebase_performance: "^0.5.0+1"
```

But I can't do it because have an errors:

```
Because firebase_remote_config >=0.8.0-dev.0 <0.9.0-dev.0 depends on firebase_remote_config_platform_interface ^0.1.0-dev.0 which depends on firebase_core ^0.5.2, firebase_remote_config >=0.8.0-dev.0 <0.9.0-dev.0 requires firebase_core ^0.5.2.
So, because EMA depends on both firebase_core ^0.7.0 and firebase_remote_config ^0.8.0-dev.0, version solving failed.
```

Flutter Firebase dependency hell !!!
What to do?

Please show guaranteed working plugins firebase pluging(storage,auth,store,crashlitics)

Comment: It does not works.If install lates version there are others errors:  Because firebase_storage >=8.0.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0 and firebase_auth >=0.20.0 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1, firebase_storage >=8.0.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth >=0.20.0 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting version conflicts. You can solve them by letting `pub` find the version that is compatible with your other dependencies. Like this:

```
firebase_remote_config: any
```

If you get more of these errors, I suggest you to put all of packages to `any` then run `flutter pub get` and finally look in the `pubspec.lock` file and see what versions you got. Now you can put those versions in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Wellcome to hell!  Because firebase_auth >=0.20.1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_auth_web ^0.3.3 which depends on http_parser ^3.1.3, firebase_auth >=0.20.1 <0.21.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 requires http_parser ^3.1.3.

Comment: Hmmm, I suggest you to put all of them to `any` then run `flutter pub get` and finally look in the `pubspec.lock` file and see what versions you got. Now you can put those versions in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: @Andrej Great answer! I didn't know that I can to put `any` and check the fixed version on `pubspec.lock`. Very useful. BTW the `firebase_remote_config` that solve the issue is `0.6.0`.

Comment: I glad it helped you!